# EPPlus OfficeOpenXml check worksheet exists without loading the whole file in memory

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using Visual Studio 2013 C#, EPPLus.dll. I have a function to check if the Excel contained the worksheet provided. Below are the code that i used, I've notice that in this case EPPlus is loading all the content of the Excel file into memory before checking the worksheet.

Any other way that we can do to reduce this? I'm reading a lot of large Excel files with many sheets and i need to get the file with the stated sheetname only.

```
    internal static bool SheetExist(string fullFilePath, string sheetName)
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fullFilePath)))
        {
            return package.Workbook.Worksheets.Any(sheet => sheet.Name == sheetName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can not get list of sheets from excel package until you will not load file into excel package. Take a look at constructors of ExcelPackage class. You can directly load the file or you can load file as stream.

Answer (score 1):

I've found alternative by using OleDbConnection, using this you can just get the sheet information without loading all the data.

```
    internal static bool SheetExist(string fullFilePath, string sheetName)
    {
        var connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO'",fullFilePath)
        var excelSheetName = "'" + sheetName + "$'";
        using (OleDbConnection excelCon = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            excelCon.Open();
            try
            {
                var dtSheets = excelCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                if (dtSheets == null) return false;
                var sheetList = dtSheets.Select().ToList();
                return sheetList.Any(sheet => sheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() == excelSheetName);
            }
            finally
            {
                excelCon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's faster, but you are opening the whole file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I check the existence of worksheet in following way. I am using EPPlus library.

```
   ExcelPackage objExcelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
   if (objExcelPackage.Workbook?.Worksheets?.Count > 0)
   {
     // Generate Excel file object
     // send email with attachment 
   }
```